# creating a mailing lists to sending mass email in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to create a mailing list via asp.net .I've studied a lots of article about it . but all of them were the same .in those article was written that I should use this code

```
var list = from c in context.Emails orderby c.EmailAddress select c.EmailAddress;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
foreach (var c in list)  
{  
    try
    {

        mail.From = new MailAddress(txtfrom.Text);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(c.ToString()));
        mail.Subject = txtSub.Text;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
        }
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Send(mail); 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

so the question is that ,is this way really useful and successful to sending lots of emails? (for example 2000 emails?)
in those articles was written that i should put delay after each period times (for example after sending 50 emails).and I wanna know how to make delay between sending emails.
I'm looking for a perfessional way to create this project
I was wondering if someone gives me open source mailing list in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the code like this

```
var list = from c in context.Emails orderby c.EmailAddress select c.EmailAddress;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
try
{

    mail.From = new MailAddress(txtfrom.Text);
    foreach (var c in list)  
    {  
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(c.ToString()));
    }
    mail.Subject = txtSub.Text;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
    }
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Send(mail); 
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //exception handling
}
```

At least, smtp.Send() is invoked only once.

Comment: that's not my problem I wanna know is there any other way to do this project?I mean some more prefessional way

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiple threads, here is an example; [msdn forum sendin bulk mails](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/csharpgeneral/thread/51a9aa66-80ec-440d-ae16-5341dc50924f)

Comment: I've  used that before it's a good way but I dont have any problem with performance .what important to me is sending all emails successfully

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have some time limit for running you script (i.e 30 seconds). I suggest split into 2 steps:

1. format e-mails you need and write them into database table (with status - "not sent")
2. run another script/program, select **N** e-mails from table, send and mark them as "sent"
3. wait/sleep **N** seconds
4. repeat 2nd step

This lets you to send almost unlimit number of e-mails, w/o timeout
Also - pay attention if you have some limit on sending e-mails per hour/day on your hosting!

Answer (score 0):

Create work items for emails to be sent and push them to queue. Then use as many competing consumers (aka workers) as you want to send those emails.

Answer (score 0):

The asp app only needs to create an XML with the info and save it.

Use a windows service with a filewatcher. This service only detect the creation of the list in XML and send it.